# Postgres PG::ConnectionBad error coming while starting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3

I tried starting the rails server and its giving the following issue:

```
neha@SCS-I82:~/work/code/$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 3.2.22 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/neha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@canvas/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize': FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "postgres", database "dev2", SSL off (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

When I try to start the postgresql service its giving the following error:

```
neha@SCS-I82:~/work/code/$ sudo service postgresql start 
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                      * Error: Port conflict: another instance is already running on /var/run/postgresql with port 5432
                                                                                                                                        [fail]
```

My /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf file is as:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Also checked by killing the running process on port 5432 as:

```
neha@SCS-I82:~/work/code/lms(ac-99)$ sudo lsof -t -i:3000
neha@SCS-I82:~/work/code/lms(ac-99)$ sudo lsof -t -i:5432
9981
neha@SCS-I82:~/work/code/lms(ac-99)$ sudo kill -9 9981
neha@SCS-I82:~/work/code/lms(ac-99)$ sudo service postgresql start 
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                      * Error: Port conflict: another instance is already running on /var/run/postgresql with port 5432
```

Can someone please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

It may your port 3000 already allocated for another server.
for fix this issue ,You may try below command

$ lsof -i:3000

```
when you press enter you will get below output like 

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    12036  tps   12u  IPv4 331030      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

$ kill -9 12036

above command kill the PID after that run rails s

Comment: ohhh then rails s should work !!! 
ok .. try to use "$ netstat -tulpn " this command.